# ElasticSearch Bad Request

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch version 6.3.1. and I am updating my document using the update by query. with some condition. here is the update_by_query example:

```
POST test/_update_by_query
    "script": {
        "source": "ctx._source.title = params.title;",
        "params": {
            "title": "demo"
        }

    },
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "term": {
                    "_id": "123"
                }
            }]
        }
    }
 }
```

but elasticsearch giving me error as: "Bad Request".
I am not able to reproduce this issue. please let me know the exact cause of this issue so I can find the solution for the same.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue related to parenthesis closing,Try following query

```
POST test/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.title = params.title",
    "params": {
      "title": "demo"
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "_id": "123"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Which is equivalent to below curl command

```
curl -XPOST '{ES_ADDR}:{ES_PORT}/test/_update_by_query' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.title = params.title;",
    "params": {
      "title": "demo"
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "_id": "123"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```